# LINQ to Entities: Unable to cast Int32 to Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ to Entity query that I would like to execute, and on my computer and database the query works fine, but on another computer and database I get this error: `Unable to cast System.Int32 to System.Object. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types`

Here is my query:

```
from S in dataContext.ItemLines
from A in dataContext.ItemLineInfoes on S.InfoAutoKey equals A.InfoAutoKey
group A by new { A.No, A.ContactID, A.InfoAutoKey }
select new
{
    g.Key.No,
    g.Key.ContactID,
    Total = (double?)dataContext.ItemLines.Where(S=>S.InfoAutoKey == g.Key.InfoAutoKey && S.Type = "X").Sum(X=>X.Value * Math.abs(X.Qty)))
}
```

Database schema is as such:

ItemLine:

```
Value: float
Qty: float
Type: nvarchar
InfoAutoKey: bigint
```

ItemLineInfo:

```
InfoAutoKey: bigint
No: bigint
ContactID: nvarchar
```

ItemLineInfo Entity:

```
public long InfoAutoKey { get; set; }
public long No { get; set; }
public string ContactID { get; set; }
```

ItemLine Entity:

```
public long InfoAutoKey {get;set;}
public double Qty {get;set;}
public double Value {get;set;}
public string Type {get;set;}
```

Note: both databases have the same schema on both computers.
ِAnd there are no null Qty and Value values.

Comment: You say _"on another computer and database"_. Does that other database have the same schema? It's a bit hard for us to debug your program; we really no nothing about your DB schema nor your C# types

Comment: Yes, it is the same schema. I will edit the question to include the schema in a second, please excuse me.

Comment: And the declarations of the `ItemLines` and `ItemLineInfoes` classes (at least the properties)?

Comment: They are the same as the ones I listed, I will also add them to the question just in case.

Comment: Is it possible your other database has a null in `X.Value` or `X.Qty`? I think I have seen this when the database column has a null and the type for the class property is not `Nullable`.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible, but who knows. Would adding a double? cast to X.Value and X.Qty solve that?

Comment: No, I tested it out. There are no null values.

Comment: Please add a tag for the EF version you're using.